# stream.read gives corrupted bytes

Tags: c#, stream

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

int sizeToRead = (int)response.ContentLength;
int sizeRead = 0;
int buffer = 1;
byte[] bytes = new byte[sizeToRead];
while (sizeToRead > 0)
{
    int rs = sizeToRead > buffer ? buffer : sizeToRead;
    stream.Read(bytes, sizeRead, rs);
    sizeToRead -= rs;
    sizeRead += rs;
}

stream.Close();
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("c:\\tmp\\b.mp3", bytes);
```

I have the above piece of code. Its purpose is to download a mp3 file from somewhere and save it to c:\tmp\filename. And it works perfectly.

However, if i change the buffer size to something not 1, say 512. The downloaded mp3 file will be scratchy. I have compared the file downloaded by my program with the one downloaded via browser, I found that some bytes of the mp3 file downloaded by my program are set to 0 (their file sizes are same thought).

Besides, I have also used fiddler to monitor the traffic when I use the above piece of code to download the mp3 file. I diffed the mp3 downloaded from my program and the browser, all the bytes are same.

So, I guess the problem is inside the stream reader or the reading process. Does anyone know why does it happen? and how to solve it without setting the buffer size to 1?

Comment: Why even use  a loop, reading 1 (!) byte at a time, when you have already created a `new byte[sizeToRead]` ?

Comment: Why not just use `stream.ReadToEnd()` since you're  not really doing anything between reads anyways?

Comment: FYI  your WebResponse and Stream need to be in using blocks: `using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()){using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream()){int sizeToRead = (int)response.ContentLength; // ...}}`

Comment: @HenkHolterman As I was tring to make the buffer to be 512 or something bigger, I was just too lazy to re-write it

Comment: @D Stanley I don't think Stream has that method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Stream.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read.aspx) returns an `int` that tells you how many bytes were *actually* read. If you're dealing with a stream you had better actually take in that information and act on it.

To put it another way, just because you *asked* for 2 bytes to be read, doesn't mean that your buffer contains 2 valid bytes.

If you need to retrieve a particular number of bytes (that you know of), then you should loop until you've obtained that number of bytes.

Comment: good point, under what situation will the read_byte!=buffer_size except reading the last block?

Comment: @Alvin  - so many situations as to not be possible to enumerate them. It's easier to enumerate the situations where it *will* match - in that, the OS has to have enough data available to fill your buffer at the point at which you call `Read`. That, in turn, depends on where the stream is coming from (networks are `<<<` slower than memory). The only *guaranteed* contract on `Stream.Read` is that (if it obtained any data) it obtained **at least 1 byte**. There's no other guarantee.

Comment: Very interesting! helped me a lot
Here is what I did in order to solve the same issue I had:

int readBytes = 0;
                    while ((readBytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        writer.Write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                        writer.Flush();
                        bytesDownloaded += buffer.Length;
                        this.DownloadProgress = (int)((bytesDownloaded * 100) / totalFileBytes);
                    }

Answer (score 1):

Is stream.Read() returning the same value as rs?  Try this:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[sizeToRead];
while (sizeToRead > 0) {
    int rs = sizeToRead > buffer ? buffer : sizeToRead;
    rs = stream.Read(bytes, sizeRead, rs);
    sizeToRead -= rs;
    sizeRead += rs;
}
```